# Permutation tests by shuffling variable 1000 times for regression -R

Tags: r, permutation

I have a regression I'd like to use permutation tests with. I want to shuffle my independent variable and re-run the regression 1000 times. In running the regression, I am hoping to calculate a p value for each coefficient in the regression by summing the number of times the coefficient for the permutation is greater than or equal to the coefficient from my initial regression (regression without the shuffled variable).

I have constructed some code for this, but 1) it is extremely slow (especially with the addition of more covariates/interaction effects) and 2) the for loop needs to be run for each coefficient.

```
initial<-lm(y~x*x1, data=df)
summary(initial)

N=1000
PermuteFunction<-function(y=df$y, x=df$x, x1=df$x1)){
  model.resample=lm(y~sample(x, replace=F)*x1)
  #permutes predictor, then runs model
  sum=summary(model.resample)$coefficients[2]
  sum1=summary(model.resample)$coefficients[3]
  return(sum)
}

sum=numeric(N)
sum1=numeric(N)
for (i in 1:N){
  sum[i]<-PermuteFunction()
  sum1[i]<-PermuteFunction()}


#calculating p-value
length(sum[sum>=initial$coefficients[2]])/N
length(sum[sum1>=initial$coefficients[2]])/N
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I've seen other questions related to permutation tests on this forum, but wasn't able to find one that looked to calculate a p-value for each coefficient. `lmPerm` didn't seem like it was for shuffling variables, either (unless I misunderstood its function)

Comment: Have you looked at the `infer` package? I think it does what you need. There's an associated book too - moderndive.com

Comment: The `initial` model has two regressors and their interaction, `PermuteFunction` fits only one. Is this right? How can you compare the coefficients, then?

Comment: Two things that might speed it up would be to replace `sum=summary(model.resample)$coefficients[2]` with `sum <- coef(model.rsample)[2]` since `summary` computes a bunch of stuff you don't need. Also `sum <- replicate(1000, PermuteFunction)` might be faster than the loop.

Comment: @Rui, you're right, I have to do the same process for each coefficient. Edited the code to show how I was doing that

Comment: also see the `lmPerm` package ...

Comment: @dcarlson ```sum <- replicate(1000, PermuteFunction)``` creates a list of 1000 rows where the function is repeated 1000 times. Should it be ```sum <- replicate(1000, {PermuteFunction})```

Comment: Yes or `sum <- replicate(1000, PermuteFunction())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is not slow, it outputs `sim`(not `sum`, the name of a base R function) after a noticeable delay. See also [dcarlon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67348931/permutation-tests-by-shuffling-variable-1000-times-for-regression-r/67350453#comment119045050_67348931).
The function's arguments are:

1. `data` - the data set;
2. `regr` - the name of the regressor as a character string;
3. `resp` - the name of the response as a character string.

Tested with builtin data set `iris`.

```
PermuteFunction <- function(data, regr, resp){
  i <- sample(nrow(data))
  x <- data[i, regr]
  y <- data[[resp]]
  coef(lm(y ~ x))[2]
}

initial <- coef(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, iris))[2]

set.seed(2021)
R <- 1e3
sim <- replicate(R, PermuteFunction(iris, "Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length"))

mean(sim >= initial)
#[1] 0.946
```

---

### Edit.

If all the coefficients are needed, the following function will compare the initial model's coefficients with the regression's using `rowMeans`.

```
PermuteFunction <- function(data, regr, resp){
  i <- sample(nrow(data))
  x <- data[i, regr]
  y <- data[[resp]]
  d <- cbind.data.frame(y, x)
  names(d) <- c(resp, regr)
  regr <- paste(regr, collapse = "+")
  fmla <- as.formula(paste(resp, regr, sep = "~"))
  coef(lm(fmla, data = d))
}

initial <- coef(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, iris))
```

Now test the function. Note that the first test gives the same 0.946 for the slope.

```
set.seed(2021)
R <- 1e3
sim <- replicate(R, PermuteFunction(iris, "Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length"))

rowMeans(sim >= initial)
#(Intercept) Sepal.Width 
#      0.054       0.946
```

Now a test with 2 regressors.

```
initial2 <- coef(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, iris))

sim2 <- replicate(R, PermuteFunction(iris, c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length"), "Sepal.Length"))
rowMeans(sim2 >= initial)
# (Intercept)  Sepal.Width Petal.Length 
#       0.562        0.461        0.500
```

Comment: Neat approach, thanks! If I'm understanding correctly though, this would need to be done for one coefficient at a time. I'd like the results for all of the coefficients in the regression